# Using Select on list of vectors

Tags: data, vector

I have a dataset, where each element in the list is a vector as in

```
data = Table[{i, 2 i, 3 i}, {i, 1, 10}]
```

As an example, I am interested in the entries where the last vector-element is greater than 6. The [page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Select.html) in the Documentation Center only goes through the 1-dimensional case - is there a way to generalize to a vector-case?

One alternative would be to use a `For`-loop, but computationally I think that is less efficient than `Select`.

Comment: There are many ways, e.g. `Select[Table[{i, 2 i, 3 i}, {i, 1, 10}], #[[3]] > 6 &]`. This has been asked many times, so you may find more answers if you look a bit at this site.

Comment: You can also use Cases: Cases[data,{_,_,x_}/;x>6]

Comment: This would be faster, `Pick[#, 1 - UnitStep[6 - #[[All, 3]]], 1] &@Table[{i, 2 i, 3 i}, {i, 1, 10}]`

Answer (score 3):

There is one way:

```
data = Table[{i, 2 i, 3 i}, {i, 1, 10}];
Select[data, #[[-1]] > 6 &]
```

> {{3,6,9},{4,8,12},{5,10,15},{6,12,18},{7,14,21},{8,16,24},{9,18,27},{10,20,30}}

And another form is:

```
Cases[data, x_ /; x[[-1]] > 6, {1}]
```

And:

```
Cases[data, x_?(#[[-1]] > 6 &), {1}]
```

All with similar performace. I prefer `Select`.

Comment: I would make this even more general by defining `makeTest[index_Integer, cutOff_?NumericQ] := #1[[index]] > cutOff &`, which can be used, for example, as `Select[data, makeTest[3, 6]]` or `Select[data, makeTest[-1, 6]]` to solve the OP's example problem, but also allows selecting for any cutoff point as well as any column in the data points.